I have an active multiple-entry C1 US visa. I also have a Canadian citizenship certificate. Need to travel (not transit) US in 20 days. My options?
Just some more context:
I have not applied for the Canadian passport yet, hence this post. I'm looking to visit a close friend in roughly 20 days. I work for a US company. I have an active C1 visa and an expired B1 visa (4 years ago).
To my understanding, the transit visa I have is useless here(?). And due to a short timeframe the NEXUS card might also not make it in time (the website states that it'd take roughly 30 days). Which kinda leaves me with the only option that is to obtain a tourist visa ASAP.

Why do you have a U.S. transit visa even though you can visit (and hence, surely, transit through) the U.S. as a Canadian citizen? Does the visa work without a passport? (The C1 website seems to indicate that the visa will be attached to your passport anyway.) Isn't it harder to obtain the visa than a Canadian passport? -- Unrelated: I'm not sure whether the immigration officer may become suspicious of somebody with an expired business visa entering for "tourism" (quotes are in the mind of the officer).

Canadian citizens traveling on a Canadian passport do not require a visa to visit the US. If you are now a Canadian citizen, your easiest way forward is to apply for a passport. If you apply at a location which offers "express pickup", you can get your passport in 2–9 business days, which should be plenty quick enough for a trip in 20 days. You can then travel only with your new passport; a NEXUS card is not necessary.
Otherwise, you are correct that a C-1 visa is not valid for a visit to the United States if the US is your destination, so you would have to apply for a new US B visa on your old passport. It will be very difficult, quite likely impossible, to do so on short notice.

Thanks for the answer. Looks like everyone agrees on the passport solution here (thanks everyone!)
